# django-filter search filed not able to recognize and filter the None value

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-filter

I'm using django-filter:

filter.py:

```
import django_filters

TYPE_CHOICES = (('One', 'One'), ('Two', 'Two'),(None,None))

class MyFilterSet(django_filters.FilterSet):
    
    Type = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=TYPE_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = Mymodel
        fields = ['Type ']
```

In the UI form select filed, when I choice the None ,and submit ,the system can't find the None value one. Nothing happen.

I have tried convert the None to sting None ,but it still not work.

Any friend can help ?

Comment: I'm guessing that None is getting mapped to NULL in the database, and in SQL NULL != NULL. Have you tried the workaround for ChoiceFilter shown in the docs? https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/tips.html#solution-2-using-choicefilter-s-null-choice

Comment: Yes,it not work.